How to handle multiple tabs using Playwright Java & POM and interact with elements inside the new tab
How to handle multiple tabs using Playwright Java & POM and interact with elements inside the new tab?
I am using PageBase class and here is the basic content of it
public class PageBase {

    Page page;
    BrowserContext context;

    public PageBase(Page page) {
        this.page = page;
        this.context = page.context();
    }

    public void clickOnElement(Locator elementLocator) {
        elementLocator.click();
    }

}

And Also TestBase Class:
public class TestBase {
    public Playwright playwright = Playwright.create();
    public Browser browser;
    public BrowserContext context;
    public Page page;

    @BeforeTest
    public void startBrowser() {
        browser = playwright.chromium().launch(new BrowserType.LaunchOptions().setHeadless(false));
        context = browser.newContext();

        // Start tracing before creating / navigating a page.
        context.tracing().start(new Tracing.StartOptions()
                .setScreenshots(true)
                .setSnapshots(true)
                .setSources(true));
        page = context.newPage();
        page.navigate("Website URL");

    }

there is a button I click on and it opens a new tab so I want to create a generic method to allow me to move between tabs by giving it the tab index only like I do in selenium for example
public void switchToTab(int tabIndex) {
    ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<>(driver.getWindowHandles());
    if (tabIndex < tabs.size()) {
        driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(tabIndex));
    } else {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Invalid tab index: " + tabIndex);
    }
}

can anyone tell me how to implement the same function but in playwright ?
I tried to create a generic function to allow me to move between browser tabs but i couldn't interact with the elements inside the new tab

Please use triple backticks to format code blocks and provide the page you're automating, along with a runnable [mcve] of the Playwright code you're attempting to write to automate it. Thanks.

According to the docs you should wait for the new page/tab event such that you have a new page context for the new tab which you can interact with.
By just switching the tab you don't have a page context for that page.

https://playwright.dev/java/docs/pages#handling-new-pages

